# How to find out the extension ID of extensions that is installed in chrome using python which is similar to executing JavaScript in console?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

Using JS, it is possible to find the extension ID by using 
`chrome.runtime.id` and returns the ID of the extension when run in console.

Comment: Show your Python code.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, I did not get any possible python code for finding the extension ID as such, instead, while running `chrome.runtime.id` in console, I get the extension. I wanted the same exact thing to be implemented in python.